# Perl on Netbeans IDE 8.0

Tags: perl, netbeans, plugins

Is it possible to create and run a perl project in Netbeans 8.0?

I followed the steps described here (http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/perl-netbeans-ide-beta-2) but got no luck.

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but the EPIC plugin in eclipse works great...

Comment: Thank you @Lucas.But because I'm currently using Netbeans for all my projects I really wanted to know if I could program in perl on netbeans 8.0 IDE. The EPIC plugin works fine in Eclipse. But I want to  work in netbeans so i don't have to have projects in one IDE and others in another. But thank u for your kind response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl On NetBeans for NetBeans 8 is in development. Expect something to be released very soon (target Aug 2014). :)

Comment: I've taken a look at the beta -- it is quite impressive.  Will the release coming in August be a plugin for Netbeans to run alongside the rest of the Netbeans IDE, or will it be a stand-alone executable like the Beta v0.2 is, currently?  I do quite a bit of Java and Perl together (linux and OSX), and a single, integrated platform would make things soooo much easier.

Comment: Going forward, all releases would be done in both formats - plugin and standalone. This way, you can choose to download anything that suits your requirement. :)